# Porting an iPhone PhoneGap project to Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I have an app made using jquerymobile+phonegap, and running under iOS. The surpise arrived when I tried to port the app to phoneGap for WP7: I created a new phonegap project using its template for visual studio 2010, and then replaced the content of the WWW folder, and included it into the project.

The project compiled, but when I run the app on the emulator, none of the images is displayed, and the javascript also is not working.

Any idea why is this happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your image and go to properties and set it as Content instead of a Resource.  I bet that is your problem, at least for your images not displaying.